# How emplace_back() works without variadic templates in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Using Visual Studio 2012 with toolset v110 I can use container's `emplace_back()` function but can't use `std::forward` with variadic templates - accepting any amount of arguments. How is it done?

As example, `make_unique<>()` won't compile:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&&... params)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Ts>(params)...));
}
```

Comment: Why you can't use `std::forward` with variadic templates? Show what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this official list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368(v=vs.120).aspx#corelanguagetable) of supported C++11 language features, the variadic templates are not supported in VS 2012.

And there is the following note on the same page below:

> **Variadics:** Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012 had a scheme for
>   simulating variadic templates. In Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013,
>   the simulations are gone and variadics are fully implemented. If your
>   code relies on the old simulated variadics behavior, you have to fix
>   it. However, the switch to real variadic templates has improved
>   compile times and reduced compiler memory consumption.

And on [another page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx) there is this note telling how the simulation have been done:

> Over the years, we've simulated variadic templates with two different systems of "faux variadic" preprocessor macros - the first
>   system involved repeatedly including subheaders, while the second
>   system (more elegant, as far as crawling horrors go) eliminated the
>   subheaders and replaced them with big backslash-continued macros that
>   were stamped out by other macros.  Functions that were supposed to be
>   true variadic, like make_shared(args...), were actually implemented
>   with overloads: make_shared(), make_shared(arg0),
>   make_shared(arg0, arg1), etc.  Classes that were supposed to be
>   true variadic, like tuple, were actually implemented with
>   default template arguments and partial specializations.  This allowed
>   us to bring you make_shared/tuple/etc. years ago, but it had lots of
>   problems.  The macros were very difficult to maintain, making it hard
>   to find and fix bugs in the affected code.  Spamming out so many
>   overloads and specializations increased compile times, and degraded
>   Intellisense.  Finally, there was the infinity problem.  We originally
>   stamped out overloads/specializations for 0 to 10 arguments inclusive,
>   but as the amount of variadic machinery increased from TR1 through
>   C++0x's evolution to C++11's final form, we lowered infinity from 10
>   to 5 in Visual C++ 2012 in order to improve compile times for most
>   users (we provided a way to request the old limit of 10 through a
>   macro, _VARIADIC_MAX).

Comment: and I'm wondering how the simulations work. I believe, it's just some stack of defines, what may not work with number of arguments more then some number

Comment: @AndrewLavq Yep, it's ["up to infinity arguments, infinity being 5 by default"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GWjbRpMHn0&feature=youtu.be&t=20m36s).